# Cannot see Deployment Source options in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm writing this simple answer to help others that would otherwise have had to spend hours getting confused by every tutorial out there.

My issue:
Newbie to Azure web apps and have been trying to learn how to deploy via GitHub. Every tutorial and video I checked out showed that as soon as you create a Web App then go to the Deployment options screen it lets you choose how you want to deploy it.

However I was not seeing this in mine - it was as if it was pre-configured for me but there was no ftp or GitHub option showing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The problem may be because I had used the node.js empty template to create my web app and it preconfigured something for me (though I don't see why this should be the case); but in any case I went to the Deployment options screen, pressed the Disconnect button. Waited then hit settings, and hey presto I finally got to where all the tutorials were talking about.